# How can I use single query to insert multiple records from Dataset into SQL Server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a dataset in ADO.NET containing multiple records from user side. I need to insert all those rows in single query into the database, in order to avoid multiple queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like a Bulk copy would be an answer. The example in Code Project below show how to do it using a DataTable, but you should be able to change the example around to use a DataSet.

Below is an small part of the code which covers to conenction and exection in SQL Server (taken from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataTableToDataBase.aspx)).

The key part to notice is the bulkcopy.WriteToServer(**SourceTable**); were the SourceTable would be the part of the DataSet you would pass to it

```
//First create a connection string to destination database
string connectionString;
connectionString = <EM>YourConnectionString</EM>and
    Initial Catalog=TestSMODatabase";

//Open a connection with destination database;
using (SqlConnection connection = 
       new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   //Open bulkcopy connection.
   using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
   {
    //Set destination table name
    //to table previously created.
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TestTable";

    try
    {
       bulkcopy.WriteToServer(SourceTable); // SourceTable would come from your DataSet
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    connection.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Setting an appropriate BatchSize and using SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock may result in much better performance. Test for your scenario.  See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2009/11/30/sqlbulkcopy-performance-analysis.aspx for detailed analysis.

Answer (score 3):

While `SqlBulkCopy` works for bulk inserts, you can't do bulk updates. This may or may not be an issue for you, but in any case you can use a stored procedure which utilises [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to allow for bulk inserts and updates. You'll also need [sp_xml_preparedocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx) and [sp_xml_removedocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190353.aspx).

Another great advantage of this method is that you can get the ids of the entities you just bulk inserted, using the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

**Example Of A Bulk Insert.**

Assuming you have defined a parameter `@p_XmlData VARCHAR(MAX)` on the stored proc defining the data to insert or update. For an example of the XML you need to pass in, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *, 0 AS __ORDERBY FROM dbo.YourEntity AS YourEntity FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('ROOT')
```

Then the stored procedure will look something like this

```
DECLARE @hDoc INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @p_XmlData

INSERT INTO dbo.YourEntity
(
        [Field1],
        [Field2]
)
SELECT
        XMLData.Field1,
        XMLData.Field2
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, 'ROOT/YourEntity', 1)
WITH
(
        [Field1] int,
        [Field2] varchar(50),
        [__ORDERBY] int
) AS XMLData

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Comment: Nice expansion on my answer + 1

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you send your DataTables from you DataSet to a stored procedure using a Table Valued parameter.  You can then perform one insert statement to populate the database with your dataset records.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx