# View XML data as a table

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xsd

Is there a way I can use Visual Studio to view my XML data in a tabular structure by applying the appropriate XSD to it?

Are there any other tools I can easily use for this purpose? PS: I need this for a one time use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Excel to view the XML document, as Oded mentioned.

If you're using Excel 2003, click on **Data->XML->Import**, and select the XML you'd like to view.  Excel will ask you which cell to start the import from, and then populate the spreadsheet with the XML data.

Answer (score 2):

[Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/viewing-an-xml-file-in-excel-HA001034645.aspx) has surprisingly good XML support.

It will even generate the XSD internally if needed.

Comment: How do you apply your custom schema in MS Excel?

Comment: @Raj More - You can import XSDs to Excel (called a Map in Excel) - look for "import map excel"

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for this in [XMLSpy 2011](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-grid-view.html). A fully functional, 30 day trial is available for download [here](http://www.altova.com/download/xmlspy/xml_editor_enterprise.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in SQL server quite easily using the FOR XML functionality.

A simple adaptation of the code from my answers to these questions would suffice:

- [fastest Import of a csv to a database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903974/fastest-import-of-a-csv-to-a-database-table/3905436#3905436)
- [How can I use single query to insert multiple records from Dataset into SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879687/how-can-i-use-single-query-to-insert-multiple-records-from-dataset-into-sql-serve/3879800#3879800)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question, but I've had plenty of luck opening xml files in Firefox, copying and pasting the result into Notepad, and then importing the text file as a tab delimited file into Excel.

Probably an easier way to do that, but it works for me.